# Is the reason I am getting 'NoneType' errors because I don't have a GPU on my laptop when doing opencv / maskrcnn using my webcam?

Tags: python, tensorflow, opencv, conv-neural-network

Running the code below - trying to implement the maskrcnn with opencv and my webcam.

When I set `PROCESS_IMG = False`, the output is fine, shows webcam input as well as FPS (if I set it to false).

I tried to comment out the line `s = masked_image` and below and every 4-5 seconds I would get a refresh of the webcam as well as a proper maskrcnn output overlaid on top (which is what I want).

Not assuming I'm going to get 60fps by any means, 0.2fps would be fine.

```
import os
import sys
import cv2
import time
import imutils
import numpy as np
import mrcnn.model as modellib
from mrcnn import utils, visualize
from imutils.video import WebcamVideoStream
import random

# Root directory of the project
from samples.coco.coco import CocoConfig

ROOT_DIR = os.path.abspath("./")

sys.path.append(os.path.join(ROOT_DIR, "samples/coco/"))  # To find local version

# Directory to save logs and trained model
MODEL_DIR = os.path.join(ROOT_DIR, "logs")

# Local path to trained weights file
COCO_MODEL_PATH = os.path.join(ROOT_DIR, "mask_rcnn_coco.h5")
# Download COCO trained weights from Releases if needed
if not os.path.exists(COCO_MODEL_PATH):
    utils.download_trained_weights(COCO_MODEL_PATH)

class InferenceConfig(CocoConfig):
    # Set batch size to 1 since we'll be running inference on
    # one image at a time. Batch size = GPU_COUNT * IMAGES_PER_GPU
    GPU_COUNT = 1
    IMAGES_PER_GPU = 1

config = InferenceConfig()
config.display()

# Create model object in inference mode.
model = modellib.MaskRCNN(mode="inference", model_dir=MODEL_DIR, config=config)

# Load weights trained on MS-COCO
model.load_weights(COCO_MODEL_PATH, by_name=True)

# COCO Class names
# Index of the class in the list is its ID. For example, to get ID of
# the teddy bear class, use: class_names.index('teddy bear')
class_names = ['BG', 'person', 'bicycle', 'car', 'motorcycle', 'airplane',
               'bus', 'train', 'truck', 'boat', 'traffic light',
               'fire hydrant', 'stop sign', 'parking meter', 'bench', 'bird',
               'cat', 'dog', 'horse', 'sheep', 'cow', 'elephant', 'bear',
               'zebra', 'giraffe', 'backpack', 'umbrella', 'handbag', 'tie',
               'suitcase', 'frisbee', 'skis', 'snowboard', 'sports ball',
               'kite', 'baseball bat', 'baseball glove', 'skateboard',
               'surfboard', 'tennis racket', 'bottle', 'wine glass', 'cup',
               'fork', 'knife', 'spoon', 'bowl', 'banana', 'apple',
               'sandwich', 'orange', 'broccoli', 'carrot', 'hot dog', 'pizza',
               'donut', 'cake', 'chair', 'couch', 'potted plant', 'bed',
               'dining table', 'toilet', 'tv', 'laptop', 'mouse', 'remote',
               'keyboard', 'cell phone', 'microwave', 'oven', 'toaster',
               'sink', 'refrigerator', 'book', 'clock', 'vase', 'scissors',
               'teddy bear', 'hair drier', 'toothbrush']

colors = visualize.random_colors(len(class_names))

gentle_grey = (45, 65, 79)
white = (255, 255, 255)

OPTIMIZE_CAM = True
SHOW_FPS = False
SHOW_FPS_WO_COUNTER = False  # faster
PROCESS_IMG = True


if OPTIMIZE_CAM:
    vs = WebcamVideoStream(src=0).start()
else:
    vs = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

if SHOW_FPS:
    fps_caption = "FPS: 0"
    fps_counter = 0
    start_time = time.time()

SCREEN_NAME = 'Mask RCNN LIVE'
cv2.namedWindow(SCREEN_NAME, cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cv2.setWindowProperty(SCREEN_NAME, cv2.WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN, cv2.WINDOW_FULLSCREEN)

while True:
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    if OPTIMIZE_CAM:
        frame = vs.read()
    else:
        grabbed, frame = vs.read()
        if not grabbed:
            break
    
    if SHOW_FPS_WO_COUNTER:
        start_time = time.time() # start time of the loop

    if PROCESS_IMG:    
        results = model.detect([frame])
        r = results[0]

        # Run detection
        masked_image = visualize.display_instances(frame, r['rois'], r['masks'], 
            r['class_ids'], class_names, r['scores'], colors=colors)
        
    if PROCESS_IMG:
        s = masked_image
    else:
        s = frame
    print("Image shape: {1}x{0}".format(s.shape[0], s.shape[1]))

    width = s.shape[1]
    height = s.shape[0]
    top_left_corner = (width-120, height-20)
    bott_right_corner = (width, height)
    top_left_corner_cvtext = (width-80, height-5)

    if SHOW_FPS:
        fps_counter+=1
        if (time.time() - start_time) > 5 : # every 5 second
            fps_caption = "FPS: {:.0f}".format(fps_counter / (time.time() - start_time))
            # print(fps_caption)
            fps_counter = 0
            start_time = time.time()
        ret, baseline = cv2.getTextSize(fps_caption, cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, 1)
        cv2.rectangle(s, (width - ret[0], height - ret[1] - baseline), bott_right_corner, gentle_grey, -1)
        cv2.putText(s,fps_caption, (width - ret[0], height - baseline), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, white, lineType=cv2.LINE_AA)

    if SHOW_FPS_WO_COUNTER:
        # Display the resulting frame
        fps_caption = "FPS: {:.0f}".format(1.0 / (time.time() - start_time))
        # print("FPS: ", 1.0 / (time.time() - start_time))
        
        # Put the rectangle and text on the bottom left corner
        ret, baseline = cv2.getTextSize(fps_caption, cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, 1)
        cv2.rectangle(s, (width - ret[0], height - ret[1] - baseline), bott_right_corner, gentle_grey, -1)
        cv2.putText(s, fps_caption, (width - ret[0], height - baseline),
                    cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, white, 1, lineType=cv2.LINE_AA)

    
    s = cv2.resize(s,(1920,1080))
    cv2.imshow(SCREEN_NAME, s)
    cv2.waitKey(1)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'): break
    
# When everything done, release the capture
if OPTIMIZE_CAM:
    vs.stop()
else:
    vs.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-d3debbeb3ebd> in <module>
    109     else:
    110         s = frame
--> 111     print("Image shape: {1}x{0}".format(s.shape[0], s.shape[1]))
    112 
    113     width = s.shape[1]

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

If I add this code in, I get an image with the correct mask:

```
file_names = next(os.walk(IMAGE_DIR))[2]
image = skimage.io.imread(os.path.join(IMAGE_DIR, random.choice(file_names)))

start = time.time()
# Run detection
results = model.detect([image], verbose=1)
end = time.time()
print("Time:",end-start,"seconds")

# Visualize results
r = results[0]
visualize.display_instances(image, r['rois'], r['masks'], r['class_ids'], 
                            class_names, r['scores'])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a function that solves my problem:

```
def save_image(image, image_name, boxes, masks, class_ids, scores, class_names, filter_classs_names=None,
               scores_thresh=0.1, save_dir=None, mode=0):
    """
        image: image array
        image_name: image name
        boxes: [num_instance, (y1, x1, y2, x2, class_id)] in image coordinates.
        masks: [num_instances, height, width]
        class_ids: [num_instances]
        scores: confidence scores for each box
        class_names: list of class names of the dataset
        filter_classs_names: (optional) list of class names we want to draw
        scores_thresh: (optional) threshold of confidence scores
        save_dir: (optional) the path to store image
        mode: (optional) select the result which you want
                mode = 0 , save image with bbox,class_name,score and mask;
                mode = 1 , save image with bbox,class_name and score;
                mode = 2 , save image with class_name,score and mask;
                mode = 3 , save mask with black background;
    """
    mode_list = [0, 1, 2, 3]
    assert mode in mode_list, "mode's value should in mode_list %s" % str(mode_list)

    if save_dir is None:
        save_dir = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "output")
        if not os.path.exists(save_dir):
            os.makedirs(save_dir)

    useful_mask_indices = []

    N = boxes.shape[0]
    if not N:
        print("\n*** No instances in image %s to draw *** \n" % (image_name))
        return
    else:
        assert boxes.shape[0] == masks.shape[-1] == class_ids.shape[0]

    for i in range(N):
        # filter
        class_id = class_ids[i]
        score = scores[i] if scores is not None else None
        if score is None or score < scores_thresh:
            continue

        label = class_names[class_id]
        if (filter_classs_names is not None) and (label not in filter_classs_names):
            continue

        if not np.any(boxes[i]):
            # Skip this instance. Has no bbox. Likely lost in image cropping.
            continue

        useful_mask_indices.append(i)

    if len(useful_mask_indices) == 0:
        print("\n*** No instances in image %s to draw *** \n" % (image_name))
        return

    colors = random_colors(len(useful_mask_indices))

    if mode != 3:
        masked_image = image.astype(np.uint8).copy()
    else:
        masked_image = np.zeros(image.shape).astype(np.uint8)

    if mode != 1:
        for index, value in enumerate(useful_mask_indices):
            masked_image = visualize.apply_mask(masked_image, masks[:, :, value], colors[index])

    masked_image = Image.fromarray(masked_image)

    if mode == 3:
        masked_image.save(os.path.join(save_dir, '%s.jpg' % (image_name)))
        return

    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(masked_image)
    colors = np.array(colors).astype(int) * 255

    for index, value in enumerate(useful_mask_indices):
        class_id = class_ids[value]
        score = scores[value]
        label = class_names[class_id]

        y1, x1, y2, x2 = boxes[value]
        if mode != 2:
            color = tuple(colors[index])
            draw.rectangle((x1, y1, x2, y2), outline=color)

        # Label
        #font = ImageFont.truetype('/Library/Fonts/Arial.ttf', 15)
        draw.text((x1, y1), "%s %f" % (label, score), (255, 255, 255))

    masked_image.save(os.path.join(save_dir, '%s.jpg' % (image_name)))
```

Answer (score 1):

[`visualize.display_instances()`](https://github.com/matterport/Mask_RCNN/blob/3deaec5d902d16e1daf56b62d5971d428dc920bc/mrcnn/visualize.py#L83) doesn't return anything, so in python it returns `None` by default. So you set `masked_image` to `None` on this line:

```
masked_image = visualize.display_instances(...
```

and then you set `s` to `None` on this line:

```
s = masked_image
```

so then `s.shape` can't work and throws that error that you're getting.

Comment: If I use this code, it outputs an image (added above)

Comment: Commented everything out as above, including the line starting `s= cv2.resize(masked_image,(1920,1080))` and I got the intermittent output (every 4 seconds) from my webcam, which means `visualize.display_instances` must be producing an image

Comment: @Dev I'm not sure I fully understand. I think you might be confusing _returning_ an image and _displaying_ an image. As far as I can tell, `visualize.display_instances()` _displays_ an image, but it doesn't _return_ an image.

Comment: I see your point - I guess I am looking for a way to visualize the image in a single window instead of repeating the image+mask in the jupyter notebook output